# Insert 2D array into Linked List

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, linked-list

How can I insert 2D array into 2D linked list ?

```
JPanel[][] cells; // It is my 2D array and I put something inside it
```

```
LinkedList<JPanel> Jpanel = new LinkedList<>(); // It is my 2D Linked List
```

I want to insert cell into Jpanel.
But when I write like this it couldnt work.

```
Jpanel.add(cells);
```

Comment: That's not a 2D list; that would be a list of lists.

Comment: Yes that is my mistake

Comment: Do you want a linked list of linked lists or of arrays or something else? Anyway you need to change the `<JPanel>` to some kind of collection of JPanel